# EF 4.0 Linq to Enity query

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Hi guys i need to replicate this SQL query in Linq to Entity

```
  select * from Subscriber a
  inner join User b on a.UserId = b.Id

  where b.Username = 'Name'
```

May be some one may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from s in context.Subscribers.Include("User")
            where s.User.Username == "Name"
            select s;
```

This suppose that `Subscriber` has navigation property `User` referencing the user instance.

If you wan to use join (which is not needed) you can use this for inner join:

```
var query = from s in context.Subscribers
            join u in context.Users on s.User.Id equals u.Id
            where u.Username == "Name"
            select new 
                {
                    Subscriber = s, 
                    User = u
                };
```

or this for left outer join:

```
var query = from s in context.Subscribers
            join u in context.Users on s.User.Id equals u.Id into x
            where u.Username == "Name"
            from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
                {
                    Subscriber = s 
                    User = y,
                };
```

Comment: Is there another way to do that, without include (just curious)

Comment: Do you want `User` data loaded? Your SQL query uses `*` which loads them. If you want only `Subscriber` data without `User` date you can remove `Include`. `User` data can be also lazy loaded once needed.

Comment: i mean something like that **var query = from s in Subscribers join u in Users on s.UserId equals u.Id select new {...}**